# how to avoid .odc file to be edited

Tags: oracle, odbc, system-administration, windows-administration

I have a .odc file from which i am connecting with oracle data in excel everything is working fine annd i want to give this access to my colleague but the file which i am giving to him is editable in notepad from which he can easily able to see password so i want to protect this file to be edited and i want to encrypt this file please help

```html
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/x-ms-odc; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=ODC.Database>
<meta name=SourceType content=OLEDB>
<title>(Default)</title>
<xml id=docprops><o:DocumentProperties
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <o:Name>(Default)</o:Name>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
</xml><xml id=msodc><odc:OfficeDataConnection
  xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
   <odc:ConnectionString>Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties=&quot;**DSN=ALPHA;UID=ALXLIE;PWD=BAC123;**DBQ=ALXORCL;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;STE=F;TSZ=8192;AST=FLOAT;&quot;;Initial Catalog=(Default)</odc:ConnectionString>
   <odc:CommandType>Table</odc:CommandType>
   <odc:SSOApplicationID>786</odc:SSOApplicationID>
   <odc:CredentialsMethod>Stored</odc:CredentialsMethod>
```